# What does arg contain in an ASM function?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering

```
Main

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub     esp, 30h
mov     dword ptr [esp], 8 ; size
call    _malloc
mov     [esp+2Ch], eax
mov     dword ptr [esp+4], 4
mov     eax, [esp+2Ch]
mov     [esp], eax
call    __start

__start

arg_0= dword ptr  8
arg_4= dword ptr  0Ch

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
mov     edx, eax
sar     edx, 1Fh
shr     edx, 1Eh
add     eax, edx
and     eax, 3
sub     eax, edx
mov     [ebp+arg_4], eax
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
cmp     eax, 1
jz      short loc_80489F0
```

The code above represents a portion of a project I am working on, where I need to reverse engineer this assembly into corresponding C-Code. I believe I have the placement of the main() down on the stack where [esp] contains the pointer to malloc, and [esp+4] contains the number 4.

I am having some difficulty figuring out which arg contains, I am under the assumption arg_0 contains 4, but arg_4 has me thrown off.

What does arg_0 and arg_4 refer to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Think of the definitions as `#define arg_0 8` and `#define arg_4 0xc` in C.  They are emitted by the compiler to connect the symbolic name of the argument to its offset on the stack in a readable way. In this case e.g. `arg_4` is at positive 12 from the base pointer. In this calling convention (which looks like Microsoft), the base pointer `ebp` points to the previous base pointer, which is just under the return address.  Arguments are at positive offsets with respect to `ebp`, and local (auto) variables are at the negative offsets.

The compiler has applied an optimization in `Main` to build the stack frame for both calls to `malloc` and `_start` with one setting of `esp`.  To see what is happening, draw a picture of 48 bytes of the stack allocated by the `sub esp, 30h`  instruction and trace each instruction from there carefully. The truth will out.